# Future method cannot be called from a future or batch method on Scheduled job

Tags: apex, callout, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, scheduled-job

I have found this issue when trying to do a callout from an scheduled job and I can't get it to work properly.

Schedule class:

```
global class TM_LATAMCargaModeladoSchedulable implements Schedulable {

  global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
    
    TM_LATAMCargaModeladosController job = new TM_LATAMCargaModeladosController();
    job.query = 'SELECT Id, Marcas__c, Credencial_nombrado__c FROM TM_AgregarMarcaModelo_Callout__mdt';
    Database.executeBatch(job);
  }
}
```

My batch class has a `@future(callout=true)` method:

```
global class TM_LATAMCargaModeladosController implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
  global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
  }
  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<TM_AgregarMarcaModelo_Callout__mdt> mdtLIST){
    //Just putting the future call for this question
    TM_LATAMCargaModeladosController.calloutFUTURE();
  } 
  @future(callout=true)
  private static void calloutFUTURE(){
    //When calling this it gives me the following error
    //Future method cannot be called from a future or batch method
  }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Regards,

Comment: You likely need to implement `Database.AllowsCallouts` on your batchable. Take a look at [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm)

Comment: Also make sure to run your batch in 100. If you run by default then it might fail as there is a limit of callouts which can be made within batch.